# Page scrolls on end key being pressed with return false

Tags: jquery

I have a `keydown` event on my body tag, and I have it listening for the `end` key (keycode 35), and the `home` button (keycode 36).

In my `if` blocks, I have the last line of it as `return false;`. Yet my page still scrolls! I've tried the `return false;` in multiple different places within my `if` block, tried using `e.preventDefault();`, as well as or instead of `e.bubbles = false;`. This is my code:

```
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 83)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            editForm();
            return false;
        }
        else if(e.which == 35) 
        { 
            /* [end] key hit */
            console.log("end key hit!");
            return false;   
        }
        else if(e.which == 36) 
        {
            /* [home] key hit */
            console.log("home key hit!");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me with this confusing issue? I really need it not to scroll on these two keys. Cheers!

***EDIT***
I have narrowed the problem down a little. It seems to be an issue with jScrollPane. I will investigate further and report back. Sorry for the hassle guys.

Comment: You have a syntax error (after the end key `return false;` an errant `}`.  It seems to work otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like jScrollPane is using keyCode 35 as well. Go to the un-minified source code of jScrollPane (URL below) page and search for 35.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js

Comment: I know that I've got jQuery included properly, this is a small snippet of code that I'm using on my page.

Comment: Updated my answer again. :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is use document instead of body:

```
$(document).keydown(.....
```

Second thing I'd try is using different events, use keydown and keyup and keypress and block it in all 3. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: I tried just replacing `document`, and something interesting has happened. Now, the Home key won't fire unless the page is at the top, and the End key won't fire won't fire until the page is at the bottom.