# Don't scroll jScrollPane with home/end keys

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have a page that listens for the Home and End keys, and then when when I put jScrollPane on my window, it now scrolls as well, and I don't want that. How can I stop the window scrolling when hitting Home or End? `return false;` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dejan.S Why? I listen for the keycode 35 and 36. They worked before I put jScrollPane in, I put it in, it then scrolls. Comment out, works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you attach the listener before jScrollPane does:

```
$(elem).on( "keydown", function(e){
    if( e.which === 35 || e.which === 36 ) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}).jScrollPane( ... )
```

Comment: It stopped the scrolling, but because of the `e.stop[Immediate]Propogation()`, it then didn't bubble up to the `keydown` function on my `$(document)` element. However, [Anthony's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14252047/563460) helped. I simply commented out the code in the jscrollerpane js file.